# Prove $A\cap f^{-1}(z)\subset \cup_{i=1}^{n} O_i$ if $A\cap f^{-1}(y)\subset \cup_{i=1}^{n} O_i$ and $z$ is close enough to $y$ when $A$ is compact

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, measure-theory

I want to prove

> Let $A$ be a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$ and $f$ be a continuous function defined on $A$. If $A\cap f^{-1}(y)\subset \cup_{i=1}^{n} O_i$ for a given $y$, where $\{O_i\}_{i=1}^n$ is a collection of open sets, then $A\cap f^{-1}(z)\subset \cup_{i=1}^{n} O_i$ for any $z$ close enough to $y$.

I know that the fact $A$ being compact is essential, because I can easily construct a continuous function whose inverse function is NOT continuous so that it can fail the conclusion. (In the above statement, $f$ is not necessarily bijective though.) But I'm not sure how I can make use of this compactness condition. Thanks for any tip.

Comment: What is the topological definition of close enough?  Are you wanting an open U nhood y with A cap f^-1(U) subset Cup_j O_j?  Why that union?  Why not just some open O instead?  Why is compact A necessary?  If f were a constant map, the problem would not require compact A.  Most functions don't have inverses.  Is f supposed to be bijective?

Comment: @WilliamElliot The union of $O_i$ is just more precise. Some open $O$ is OK. $f^{-1}(y):=\{x|f(x)=y\}$. If $A$ is not compact, then there exists a continuous bijective function whose inverse function is not continuous which can fail this statement.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the conclusion is false and suppose a sequence $\{z_j\}_{j=1}^{\infty}$ converges to $y$. Then for $k$ large enough I can always find a $x_k\in f^{-1}(z_k)$ such that $x_i\notin \cup_{i=1}^n O_i$. Then we get a new sequence $\{x_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ in the compact $A$. So the sequence must converge to a $x$ in $A$ by the compactness of $A$. By continuity of $f$, $\{f(x_k)\}_{k=1}^n$ converges to $y'=f(x)$ which is not possible to be equal to $y$ since $\{x_k\}$ is picked outside of the neighbor $\cup_{i=1}^{\infty}O_i$ of $f^{-1}(y)$. On the other hand, $\{f(x_k)\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ should converge to $y$ since $f(x_k)=z_k\in\{z_j\}_{j=1}^{\infty}$. Then contradiction.

Comment: Hope someone can confirm this answer.